# How to use DataItem of Android Wear

Tags: android, synchronization, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I want to sync preference between handhelds and wearables. I implement [sample code](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html) on handheld app.

```
PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
dataMap.getDataMap().putInt(COUNT_KEY, count++);
PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi
    .putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);
System.out.println(dataMap.getDataMap().getInt("COUNT_KEY"));//print 3
```

And then implement below code on wearable app. But saved count can't be retrieved.

```
 PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
 int count = dataMap.getDataMap().getInt("COUNT_KEY");
 System.out.println(count);//print 0
```

I tried in actual android handheld device and emulator of Android wear. I confirmed they are connected by using demo cards of Android Wear app.

What I need more or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With that code, you are trying to create a *second put request*, not reading the previously stored data. That's why it's empty.

**The way to access previously stored data is with the [`DataApi`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html) methods.** For example, you can get all stored data with `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems()`:

```
PendingResult<DataItemBuffer> results = Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(mGoogleApiClient);
results.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataItemBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DataItemBuffer dataItems) {
        if (dataItems.getCount() != 0) {
            DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItems.get(0));

            // This should read the correct value.
            int value = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt(COUNT_KEY);
        }

        dataItems.release();
    }
});
```

I've used this and it works. However, I'm having a problem myself, as I don't know the Uri to access a *specific* data item with `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem()`. So I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24601251/82788). If you're just testing though, `DataApi.getDataItems()` should suffice.

Another option is to use [`DataApi.addListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html#addListener%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi.DataListener%29) to be notified of changes to the storage.

Comment: I implemented this code but onResult() doesn't run. I tried pendingResult.await(); on another thread and found this process doesn't finish.

Comment: @lamrongol Did you connect to play services before?

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked connect() on [Accessing the Wearable Data Layer](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html). Now it works, thank you.